# Entity framework IQueryable with poco generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, poco, iqueryable

I've created a T4 template which generates standard Entities classes along with Interfaces for each of their properties so that I can make customized poco objects containing only the data that I want. I've also created a copy function which can convert between any of the objects which implement said entity's interface

The generated code looks like this

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DomainModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;


    public interface IRole
    {
    }
    public interface IRole_RoleId : IRole
    {
      int RoleId { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IRole_ApplicationName : IRole
    {
      string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IRole_RoleName : IRole
    {
      string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IRole_Description : IRole
    {
      string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRole_Users : IRole 
    {
      ICollection<IUser> Users { get; set; }
      IUser NewUsers();
    }

    public interface IRole__All : IRole_RoleId, 
      IRole_ApplicationName, 
      IRole_RoleName, 
      IRole_Description, 
      IRole_Users
    {
    }

    public partial class Role : IRole
    {
      public Role()
      {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
      }

      public int RoleId { get; set; }
      public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
      public string RoleName { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public static class IRoleExt
    {
      public static T CopyTo<T>(this IRole src , T dest = null  )  where T : class, IRole, new()
      {
        dest = dest ?? new T();
        dest.Copy(src);
        return dest;
      }
      public static void Copy(this IRole dest, IRole src)
      {
        var ms = new MergeStack();
        Role role;
        if((role = dest as Role) != null){
          ms.TryCopy<IRole,Role>((indexCopy) => {return indexCopy(role);}, src);
        }
        else if ((role = src as Role) != null){
          ms.TryCopy<Role,IRole>((indexCopy) => {return indexCopy(dest);}, role);
        }
        else{
          ms.TryCopy<IRole,IRole>((indexCopy) => {return indexCopy(dest);}, src);
        }
        dest.Copy(src, ms);
      }

      internal static void Copy(this IRole dest,
        IRole src,
        MergeStack ms)
      {
        dest.Set_RoleId(src.Get_RoleId());
        dest.Set_ApplicationName(src.Get_ApplicationName());
        dest.Set_RoleName(src.Get_RoleName());
        dest.Set_Description(src.Get_Description());
        dest.Set_Users(src.Get_Users(),ms);
      }
        public static Nullable<int> Get_RoleId(this IRole src)
      {
        IRole_RoleId srcIRole_RoleId;
        if((srcIRole_RoleId = src as IRole_RoleId) != null )
        {
          return srcIRole_RoleId.RoleId;
        }
        Role role;
        if((role = src as Role) != null )
        {
          return role.RoleId;
        }
          return null;

      }
        public static void Set_RoleId(this IRole dest, Nullable<int> src)
      {
        IRole_RoleId destIRole_RoleId;
        if((destIRole_RoleId = dest as IRole_RoleId) != null)
        {
           destIRole_RoleId.RoleId = src.GetValueOrDefault();
            }
        Role role;
        if((role = dest as Role) != null )
        {
          role.RoleId = src.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
      }

        public static string Get_ApplicationName(this IRole src)
      {
        IRole_ApplicationName srcIRole_ApplicationName;
        if((srcIRole_ApplicationName = src as IRole_ApplicationName) != null )
        {
          return srcIRole_ApplicationName.ApplicationName;
        }
        Role role;
        if((role = src as Role) != null )
        {
          return role.ApplicationName;
        }
          return null;

      }
        public static void Set_ApplicationName(this IRole dest, string src)
      {
        IRole_ApplicationName destIRole_ApplicationName;
        if((destIRole_ApplicationName = dest as IRole_ApplicationName) != null)
        {
           destIRole_ApplicationName.ApplicationName = src;
            }
        Role role;
        if((role = dest as Role) != null )
        {
          role.ApplicationName = src;
        }
      }

        public static string Get_RoleName(this IRole src)
      {
        IRole_RoleName srcIRole_RoleName;
        if((srcIRole_RoleName = src as IRole_RoleName) != null )
        {
          return srcIRole_RoleName.RoleName;
        }
        Role role;
        if((role = src as Role) != null )
        {
          return role.RoleName;
        }
          return null;

      }
        public static void Set_RoleName(this IRole dest, string src)
      {
        IRole_RoleName destIRole_RoleName;
        if((destIRole_RoleName = dest as IRole_RoleName) != null)
        {
           destIRole_RoleName.RoleName = src;
            }
        Role role;
        if((role = dest as Role) != null )
        {
          role.RoleName = src;
        }
      }

        public static string Get_Description(this IRole src)
      {
        IRole_Description srcIRole_Description;
        if((srcIRole_Description = src as IRole_Description) != null )
        {
          return srcIRole_Description.Description;
        }
        Role role;
        if((role = src as Role) != null )
        {
          return role.Description;
        }
          return null;

      }
        public static void Set_Description(this IRole dest, string src)
      {
        IRole_Description destIRole_Description;
        if((destIRole_Description = dest as IRole_Description) != null)
        {
           destIRole_Description.Description = src;
            }
        Role role;
        if((role = dest as Role) != null )
        {
          role.Description = src;
        }
      }

      public static ICollection<IUser> Get_Users(this Role src)
      {
        return src.Users.Cast<IUser>().ToList();
        }
        public static ICollection<IUser> Get_Users(this IRole src)
      {
        IRole_Users srcIRole_Users;
        if((srcIRole_Users = src as IRole_Users) != null )
        {
          return srcIRole_Users.Users;
        }
        Role role;
        if((role = src as Role) != null )
        {
          return role.Get_Users();
        }
          return null;
      }
      public static void Set_Users(this IRole dest, ICollection<IUser> src)
      {
        var ms = new MergeStack();
        dest.Set_Users(src, ms);
      }

      internal static void Set_Users(this IRole dest, ICollection<IUser> src, MergeStack ms)
      {
        IRole_Users destIRole_Users;
        if((destIRole_Users = dest as IRole_Users) != null)
        {
          Func<IUser,IUser> iToIFunc = (x=> 
              ms.TryCopy<IUser,IUser>((indexCopy)=>
              {
                var ret = destIRole_Users.NewUsers();
                  var exists = indexCopy(ret);
                if(null != exists)
                    ret = exists;
                  else
                  ret.Copy(x,ms);
                return ret;
              },x));
          destIRole_Users.Users = (null !=src)?
          src.Select(iToIFunc).ToList():null;
        }

        Role role;
        if((role = dest as Role) != null)
        {
          Func<IUser,User> iToEFunc = (x=> 
              ms.TryCopy<IUser,User>((indexCopy)=>
              {
                var ret = new User();
                  var exists = indexCopy(ret);
                if(null != exists)
                    ret = exists;
                  else
                  ret.Copy(x,ms);
                return ret;
              },x));
          role.Users = (null !=src)?
          src.Select(iToEFunc).ToList():null;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

That merge stack object you see is a tracker so I can handler reference loops. it looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DomainModel
{

    internal class MergeStack
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Object, Object>> _mergeObjDict = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<object, object>>();
        private readonly IList<Action> _registerActions = new List<Action>();

        public T TryCopy<TKey, T>(Func<Func<T, T>, T> func, TKey key) where T : class
        {
            if (key == null)
                return null;

            Func<T, T> act = (objToIndex) =>
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> objToObj;
                if (!_mergeObjDict.ContainsKey(objToIndex.GetType()))
                {
                    objToObj = new Dictionary<object, object>();
                    _mergeObjDict.Add(objToIndex.GetType(), objToObj);
                }
                else
                {
                    objToObj = _mergeObjDict[objToIndex.GetType()];
                }
                if (!objToObj.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    objToObj.Add(key, objToIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    return objToObj[key] as T;
                }
                return null as T;
            };
            return func(act);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all this works fine as intended, it successfully copies over all implemented properties to and from the domain model/interface.

I'm now trying to make play nice with IQueryable and lazy loading.

Right now I'm doing this

```
dbContext.Roles.Select((x)=> x.CopyTo<RolesPoco>());
```

I'd like to see if there's a way I could auto generate includes such as

```
dbContext.Roles.Select((x)=> x.Users.Include((y)=> y.someSubEntity);
```

I'd also like to see if I could put on some where clauses like this

```
//the first string is a path so something like "Roles.Users.someSubEntity"
//the second string is a IQueryable function like Where or Take
Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,List<Func<T, IQueryable<TProperty>>>> queryDict

dbContext.Roles.Select((x)=> x.CopyTo<RolesPoco>(queryDict)
```

And then the List would be some list of lambdas that can run inside of the include functions.
Anybody have any ideas on this?

**Edit**: I refactored simplified some of the code so that it could call a getter/setter even if  the class didn't implement the interface. So the properties can be accessed regardless of there being a backing field. It returns null if it's not defined.

**Edit2**: Since it seems unclear what I'm trying to achieve, let me clarify. If you go down to the remarks part of this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), you'll see some select statements. I want to generate those Expressions and then use them inside of a parent select based on whether or not the class being copied to contains the interface that implements that member. I'm avoiding linqToObject because I only need the properties defined in the CopyTo, but the Navigation properties are interfaces, which blows up entity framework. This is for Lazy loading purposes. MergeStack would be composing and returning those expressions up the tree. I got the idea from [a DaedTech blogpost](http://www.daedtech.com/faking-an-interface-mapping-in-entity-framework)

Comment: This is an interesting snippet you've posted up: I've thought of something similar in the past, although I've always thought of it as quite heavyweight. 

Would a set of DTOs and automapper not be sufficient for your requirements? Interested to hear your use case.

Comment: It actually runs pretty quickly be cause of the as and avoiding a double cast with an is check. then. It's only about 2-3x longer than a copy constructor. Also I created the DTO as an extension class IRoleExt. That's all working, but I want to make it work with IQueryable and have it be able to filter sub navigation properties

Comment: I modified the template to work by copying properties and having getter/setter extension methods on each property

Comment: Wouldn't the include be `dbContext.Roles.Include(i => i.subEntity).Select(r => r.CopyTo<RolesPoco>...);` ?

Comment: yes, but I want the Include to be auto-generated and used when i do dbContext.Roles.First().CopyTo<RolesPoco>(); so inside of my copy function, before it goes into the subEntity, it calls Include for each sub entity, and each subsubentity, making it so that everything is loaded at once instead of making multiple calls to the db

Comment: How would the `CopyTo` know the difference between a navigation property(s) and ones added that are not database related?  I would imagine it would be more efficient and extensible to have `CopyTo` only look at what was explicitly included, that way you have control over what is queried from the database, and not retrieve everything every time.

Comment: In the T4 templates I can generate based on navigation properties. I need a method for injecting nested includes into a IQueryable query so that it get's treated as an expression. e.g. foreach navigationproperty create include expression capable of taking a sub include expression capable of taking a sub include expression, etc. and it needs to know when to stop adding sub include expressions so as to not have an infinite loop of expressions.

Comment: @DrSammyD "I want to make it work with IQueryable" is impossible in the current format. `.Select(r => r.CopyTo<RolesPoco>...)` is run in LinqToObject, as you should have already noted. For this to work you need to construct this as a set of `Expression`s. There is no (general) way for `MergeStack` to be converted into an `Expression` that can run in SQL. There is a huge amount of work here in `Expression` trees, and quite frankly I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Finally...it seems that you have completely missed the point of POCOs. The point of POCOs is that you don't need to faff with separate DTOs and Entities.

Comment: @Aron I updated my answer with a clarification

Comment: Instead of trying to auto-generate `Include` calls, why not query over the POCO type directly? It is easy to have many POCO types mapped to the same table or view, and then the POCO type that you are querying over can define what gets Included in the query.

Comment: @default.kramer the only issue with that is entity framework can't do that if the poco has interfaces as the navigation properties. This is for lazy loading purposes.

Comment: I think I've made something similar before, just the other way around, for mocking purposes. My approach was like this: In the T4 template, don't give you entity just a IRole interface, give all entities an IEntity interface so you can identify them. In the CopyTo function you can use GetProperties loop through the properties of the entity. All properties that are of IEntity could be included automatically. I left my code at work tho, so I can't give a proper answer at the moment, but maybe it helps...

Comment: I'm essentially already doing that, but I didn't want to use reflection for performance reasons, and I wanted the compiler to know if the object I'm using has one of the properties. I already know what properties are there because they implement the property interface, so The issue is creating nested select expressions that aren't infinitely deep in the case of a circular reference

Answer (score 0):

Roles is IQueryable, so you need to get the Select method from the Queryable extensions class.
You also need to get the Include from the Enumerable extension class.
You then need to invoke the Select method using Role as a generic argument.
You need to construct a lambda using Expression.Lambda, Expression.Call and Expression.Property.

Comment: Any chance you can expand on that. I don't really know how to use Expression.Property Expression.Lambda or Expression.Call

Comment: This Question has more about what I'm looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229882/deep-clone-with-expression-new-and-expression-trees